# Field of coordinates in Diophantine equation

Tags: field-theory, diophantine-equations

Given any linear homogeneous Diophantine equation all points $(\alpha, \beta)$ on that line forms an infinite Abelian Group.But do there exist any operation that can turn it into a field ? I tried to think of multiplication like operation in that group. But $(\alpha_{1} \alpha_2, \beta_{1} \beta_2)$ is a point in another line (which is a different group). Is there any way to embed this field into some field ?

Comment: The "infinite abelian group" is in fact isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. No field has additive group isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: But that doesn't permit me to perform multiplication like operations involving the coordinates of that line.